# SAP HANA PAL CART, plan terminated after being inactive

Tags: hana, cart-analysis

I'm using the HANA PAL CART Function, on some datasets I get following error:

[2629] executor: plan terminated internally after being inactive for too long

What could be the reason for that? Is there maybe any timeout?

If I try the same dataset in R, it works well.